# List comprehension vs Enum.filter

Tags: elixir

I can write

```
unitlist |> Enum.filter(&(s in &1))
```

or I can write

```
for u <- unitlist, s in u, do: u
```

What is the difference in capabilities of the two constructs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular case they're identical no matter what the value of `unitlist` is -- they both accept any Enumerable and run the `s in &1` check on each item and return a new list for those returning a truthy value.

`for` has many more features than what `Enum.filter` can do alone: You can have iterate through multiple enumerables and generate a flat list of results. You can have a fallible pattern on the left of `<-` and `for` will silently skip over those items instead of throwing an error. You can modify the value returned after the check. The following code snippet demonstrates all this:

```
iex(1)> for a <- 1..3, b = 2 <- 1..3, a > 1, do: {a, b}
[{2, 2}, {3, 2}]
```

A `for` can be desugared to a combination of `Enum.map`, `if`, and `Enum.flat_map`. The above is the same as this:

```
Enum.flat_map(1..3, fn a ->
  Enum.flat_map(1..3, fn
    b = 2 ->
      if(a > 1, do: [{a, b}], else: [])
    _ ->
      []
  end)
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Comment: OK so `for` is much more powerful -- then why does `Enum.filter` exist? When would you want to use that in place of `for`?

Comment: `Enum.filter` is shorter than `for` when you just want to filter some items from a list based on a predicate. It can also be used easily in a pipeline unlike `for`.

Comment: FWIW, `for` comprehension is [transpiled into `reduce`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_erl_for.erl#L125), not nested flatmaps.

Answer (score 3):

Like [@Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46202061/2066155): In your example, it is doing the same thing. And `for` comprehension can do a lot more than filter. It could easily replace a lot of `Enum` functions.

> OK so for is much more powerful -- then why does Enum.filter exist? When would you want to use that in place of for?

Imagine asking, "Why drive your 2-door coupe to work when you could drive an RV?" :)

Some of the advantages of the `Enum` functions are that they are simpler, better chained with pipes, and can describe your intention better.

e.g.

```elixir
[1, 2, 3, 4]
|> Enum.filter(&(&1 > 2))
|> Enum.map(&to_string/1)
|> Enum.join()

# "34"
```